# How to create devuser on a Kaa single Linux node

Tags: kaa

**Description:**

I try with Kaa components on a single Linux node instead of Kaa sandbox; and I want to create a devuser with devuser role ; but on a single Linux node not a default **devuser role** for create developer user and or tenant admin.

What command should I use for create developer user and tenant admin in terminal?

[image]
**Hint:** Environment: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Desktop 64-bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to answer from MrKoin;

- First, create Kaa administrator.
- Second, under that user create a Tenant administrator;
- And then, under the Tenant administrator credentials create a Tenant
  developer.

But, first thing after create Tenant administrator, you should be access to tenant administrator panel and then create Tenant developer and access to Tenant developer panel.

For this way, you need [outgoing mail setting](http://docs.kaaproject.org/display/KAA/Administration+UI+guide) according to Administration UI guide.

**Note:** you need to **[Allow less secure apps: ON](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en)** for your email.

And then, for access to Tenant administrator or Tenant developer panel first go to login page and click **Forgot password** (**Note:** You need correct email for restore password.)

Finally, an email containing a password recovery will be sent to you. And you have access to your desired tenant panel.

Answer (score 2):

The user types in Kaa are plit by the scope and roles they have access to and manage.

Thus:

1. **Kaa administrator** is the highest level administrator of Kaa. This user can create, edit, and delete tenant administrators.

That is, this user type cannot create a Tenant Developer.

2. **Tenant administrator** is a Kaa user that manages applications, users, and event class families.
3. **Tenant developer** can create SDKs based on customer requirements, set the Kaa schemas, create endpoint groups, control the notification processes, etc.

This means that you should first create Kaa administrator. Then, under that user create a Tenant administrator and then, under the Tenant administrator credentials create a Tenant developer.

See [Tenants and applications management](http://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/v0.10.0/Administration-guide/Tenants-and-applications-management/) for more information.

These users are not OS wide and are internal to Kaa node or cluster installation.

Please check [Kaa User management REST API](http://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/v0.10.0/Programming-guide/Server-REST-APIs/#/User) documentation page for information on how to manage Kaa users with no use of Administration UI.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create Kaa Admin User
2. Modify outgoing email setting (settings -> outgoing email settings):
3. Create a Tenant (Teants -> Add tenant and creata a new tenant)
4. Click adduser button (bottom - right side)
5. Create a user and set a email and as role -> Tenant Admin. An email is sent to Tenant Admin.
6. Login as Tenant Admin
7. Create a new Tenant and as role set Tenant Dev.