# Build Kaa from source code - missing panels from Admin UI

Tags: kaa

I have built a Kaa server from the source code using the guide at the following [link](https://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/v0.10.0/Administration-guide/System-installation/Building-Kaa-server-from-source-code/). After which, I followed the guide at the following [link](https://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/v0.10.0/Administration-guide/System-installation/Single-node-installation/) to install the Kaa node service.

I am deploying the build on Ubuntu 16.04 and using MariaDB and MongoDB as the SQL and NoSQL databases respectively. I followed every step from both the guides and the server starts successfully.

I am able to navigate to the Kaa admin page using the link `http://YOUR_SERVER_HOST:8080/kaaAdmin`, and have created an admin user as well.

However, when I log in, I don't see all the panels. I only see the following panels.
[image: Admin UI]

---

I don't see the user, tenant or the application management panels. The tenant section only allows me to add a new tenant where I can only enter the tenant name and nothing else.

[image: Add tenant UI]

Is there additional step to be performed to enable the other panels? I am not sure what I am missing.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please refer to this link: [How to create devuser on a Kaa single Linux node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45649173/how-to-create-devuser-on-a-kaa-single-linux-node/46376508#46376508)

Comment: Thank you for this. It is exactly what I was looking for.